# Dependency mapping by a type of constructor parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have various report types, each one accepts a configuration of a certain type:

```
interface IConfig { ... }
interface IReport { ... }

class ConfigA : IConfig { ... }
class ConfigB : IConfig { ... }

class ReportA : IReport
{
    public ReportA (ConfigA config)
    { ... }
}

class ReportB : IReport
{
    public ReportB (ConfigB config)
    { ... }
}
```

How can I configure Unity container to resolve `IReport` by a type of a constructor argument passed?

```
var reportA = unityContainer.Resolve<IReport>(new ConfigA()); // Should be ReportA
var reportB = unityContainer.Resolve<IReport>(new ConfigB()); // Should be ReportB
```

I know that one can make a kind of factory with a mapping of types inside it, but here I want to rely on Unity and keep my objects container-unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After unsuccessful search of existing ways I've created a custom injection member that does the stuff - see this Nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityInjectionLookup)

First of all, let's suppose we have registered both reports:

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

unityContainer.RegisterType<IReport, ReportA>("ReportA");
unityContainer.RegisterType<IReport, ReportB>("ReportB");
```

Then we just add another registration of `IReport` with the `InjectionMember`:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IReport>(new InjectionConstructorLookup<IConfig>());
```

Here `IConfig` type parameters says that we'll look for `IReport`-inherited objects with a single constructor argument, inherited from `IConfig`.

Then there are two ways of resolving `IReport`. The first one is one mentioned by @Backs:

```
var reportA = unityContainer.Resolve<IReport>(new DependencyOverride<IConfig>(new ConfigA())); // Should be ReportA
var reportB = unityContainer.Resolve<IReport>(new DependencyOverride<IConfig>(new ConfigB())); // Should be ReportB
```

The second one is a delegate factory:

```
var factory = unityContainer.Resolve<Func<IConfig, IReport>>();

var reportA1 = factory(new ConfigA()); // Should be ReportA
var reportB1 = factory(new ConfigB()); // Should be ReportB
```

Call to the factory is faster due to result caching.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`DependencyOverride`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920(v=pandp.20).aspx):

```
var reportA = unityContainer.Resolve<IReport>(new DependencyOverride<IConfig>(new ConfigA()); // Should be ReportA
var reportB = unityContainer.Resolve<IReport>(new DependencyOverride<IConfig>(new ConfigB()); // Should be ReportB
```

Comment: What registrations should I add? I don't want to change them for each resolve, of course.

Comment: @stop-cran you can use any registration.

Comment: How should I make the container to infer type `ReportA` from a type of argument passed - `ConfigA`? I can make such a mapping by other means, but I wonder can I somehow do this by configuring Unity container? So I just call `Resolve` for a configured container passing `ConfigA` instance and it maps it to `ReportA` type and instanciates it.

Comment: My solution now is to introduce a dictionary to map a config type to report factory method. Maybe someone has a better solution.

Comment: Finally I made this work by a custom injection member, see my answer.